# publishing(replicating) Oracle to Sql2008r2

Tags: oracle, sql-server-2008, replication

Trying to establish transactional replication from oracle server to Sql2008 R2 instance.
I am able to set up 'Oracle publication' through Replication,New Oracle publication  wizard;every thing seems go fine up to adding articles (oracle table) and able to Map datatypes.
but when I choose Transactional Replication, it tells me that the oracle source table I choose do not have a Primary Key. Which is not true.

If choose a snapshot, it goes on a infinite loop.

I noticed that the linked server(to oracle) is using msdaOra provider, Is there a way to force Publication Wizard to use OraOLEDB.Oracle provider when it sets up associated linked server.

any help appreciated

Answer (score 3):

I have found that Oracle PK constraints are not enough for SQL Server to consider the table to have a PK. Make sure the Oracle DDL for the table does an explicit create unique index to go along with that PK. If all you have is the constraint and an organizational index in Oracle, SQL Server will disqualify it from transaction level replication. I'm still trying to figure a way around this as I don't want to add the unique index to a live, real-time data acquisition system n production. I do't know that SQL server even really NEEDs the unique index...but am thinking that rather it just needs to know the uniqueness qualifiers which it COULD get from the constraint definition alone.

Answer (score 0):

What version of Oracle? 
here's a [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152481.aspx) for some microsoft instructions. 
Make sure you have the x64 version of the Oracle Client software installed on the SQL Server - *the oracle client install needs to be the admin setup option*.
Does the replication user you have set up to connect to oracle have select access to the schema you are trying to replicate? (dumb question, but I have to ask) 
Also, have you set up transactional replication for this system before to test?
Did you test it against a source table that did not have a primary key?
 - (testing this sql 2k8 r2 box against another oracle test environment)
if so you might need to reinitialize the distribution.

you also need sql 2k8 r2 enterprise edition to to set up replication from an oracle publisher.